# Find lines intersection point with Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is it possible to find the intersection of two traces with Plotly.js?
Or, probably, it is possible to find it in javascript?
I have only arrays of x/y-coordinates for each trace.

Comment: There is no direct way of doing it. You would need to do it manually in JS.

Comment: Is this what you want? Move the sliders until the lines intersect and see if that's what you want (Edit - this may require some changes, this seems to continue the lines to infinity even if they don't intersect - but it should be a good starting point). http://jsfiddle.net/justin_c_rounds/Gd2S2/light/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in JavaScript library Turf.js using [turf.lineIntersect](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineintersect):

```
var line1 = turf.lineString([[126, -11], [129, -21]]);
var line2 = turf.lineString([[123, -18], [131, -14]]);
var intersects = turf.lineIntersect(line1, line2);
```

[image: intersection result]